# A Product function for matrix products

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I would like to use an equivalent of the product-function in mathematica, but where instead of multiplying numbers I multiply matrices?

Comment: `Apply[Dot,Table[matrixFunctionOfj,{j,n}]]` should do this.

Comment: Sometimes defining a new function for a simple task can make the code less readable. In this instance, I think that is the case because the syntax as shown by  @DanielLichtblau is concise and sufficiently expressive to be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is built in in Mathematica.
Just use the dot for multiplication.

Here are two 2x2 matrices

```
a = PauliMatrix[1]
b = PauliMatrix[3]

(* Out[49]= {{0, 1}, {1, 0}} *)
(* Out[50]= {{1, 0}, {0, -1}} *)
```

Here's a product

```
a.b

(* Out[53]= {{0, -1}, {1, 0}} *)
```

and here is the product of the same factors in reverse order

```
b.a

(* Out[52]= {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}} *)
```

There are also two interesting functions of matrices

```
MatrixPower[a, 2]

(* Out[55]= {{1, 0}, {0, 1}} *)

MatrixExp[b]

(* Out[56]= {{E, 0}, {0, 1/E}} *)
```

Hope this helps,
Wolfgang

**EDIT in response to the comment**

I'm not aware of a generalization of `Product[]` to matrices in Mathematica. 
But you could easily define it yourself

```
matrixProduct[listOfMatrices_] := Dot @@ listOfMatrices
```

Then

```
m = Table[PauliMatrix[i], {i, 1, 3}];

matrixProduct[m]

(* Out[31]= {{I, 0}, {0, I}} *)
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: It is not exactly what I asked: I would like to make an iterated product but with matrices. E.g. 
   Product[PauliMatrix[i],{i,1,3}], 
where the multiplication would be the dot . instead of the star *.

Comment: Sorry, Anne. But see the EDIT in my answer. I hope it covers now what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to use [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html), the fourth parameter of which sets the function that combines expressions:

```
m = RandomReal[9, {3, 3, 3}];

Array[m[[#]] &, 3, 1, Dot]
```

> ```
> {{606.041, 638.877, 525.972},
>  {1011.5, 1068.12, 856.671},
>  {532.56, 556.236, 435.836}}
> ```

Equivalent to:

```
Dot @@ m
```

> ```
> {{606.041, 638.877, 525.972},
>  {1011.5, 1068.12, 856.671},
>  {532.56, 556.236, 435.836}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
productF = Block[{Times = Dot}, Product[#, #2]] &;
```

Examples:

```
m = Table[PauliMatrix[i], {i, 1, 3}];

productF[j, {j, m}]
(* {{I, 0},{0, I}} *)

productF[PauliMatrix[j], {j, 3}]
(* {{I, 0},{0, I}} *)
```

---

For better emulation of `Product` one may include the `HoldAll` attribute and accept additional `Product` iterators with:

```
productF2 = Function[, Block[{Times = Dot}, Product @ ##], HoldAll];
```